# Empty model in Eloquent Global scope?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am trying to determine if a user has the ability to update a model in a global scope, but I am using permission prefixes that I normally get through a relation.

The apply code is as follows:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $user = getUser();

    if ($user === null || $user->cannot('update', $model)) {
        $builder->where('active', '=', 1);
    }
}
```

When I `dd($model)` the model is not actually instantiated so when I do my update permission check in my policy:

```
public function update(User $user, Item $item)
{
    return $user->hasAnyPermission(['edit-things', $this->prefix($item) . "-edit-item"]);
}
```

Where the prefix function looks like:

```
private function prefix(Item $item = null)
{
    if ($item !== null) {
        return $item->parentRelation->roles_permission_prefix;
    }
    $parentRelation= ParentRelation::findOrFail(request('parent_relation_id'));
    return $parentRelation->roles_permission_prefix;
}
```

It all fails due to their actaully not being a relationship. Any ideas?

Quick Edit: I am using the Spatie Permissions library if that is pertinent.

Comment: `$model` is an instance of `Query` in the context of scope

Comment: Ah, well crap. Time to go back to the drawing board then.

Comment: @devk When I `dd($model)` the type of it is not query builder but Item?

Comment: Yeah what I said wasn't exactly correct. The `$model` is an uninstantiated model, like you said. Which acts like a query with (which is why we can call query methods off of models, like `Model::where()..`) additional model-specific methods (relationships, scopes...)

Comment: @devk that makes sense. If you summarize in an answer I will make it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The only function that would break on a missing relationship is the `prefix()` function.

You can prevent `prefix()` from being called by checking if both `$model` and `$model->parentRelation` are null too in your list of conditions:

```
public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
{
    $user = getUser();

    if (   $user === null 
        || $model === null 
        || (method_exists($model, 'parent_relation') && !$model->parentRelation)
        || $user->cannot('update', $model)
    ) {
        $builder->where('active', '=', 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: The prefix is a key requirement. My issue is that the model is a false instance, is that the norm with global scopes?

Comment: Ah, yes, I've overlooked that this is a global scope. I do believe that what you want to achieve is not possible with a global scope, as you're not meant to call instance methods on those.

Comment: You would need, instead, to mimick what `spatie/permissions` does in the back-end to look for the permissions using the `$builder`.

Comment: That seems to be the way it is going. Really appreciate the effort though.